# Jquery when submit button need to validate radio button and get the id of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate my button when summit if not check the radio button it will show error but if we check, it will get the id of the button that we check. I try code as below:

Html:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="chk" id="chk1"  class="chk"/>abcd
    </label>
</div>
 <div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="chk" id="chk2" class="chk" />
        efg
    </label>
 </div>
<input type="button" value="Visualiser le résultat..."  id="btnresult" class="btn"/>
```

Jquery:

```
   $('#btnresult').on('click',function(){   
                        if ( ! $('input.chk').is(':checked') ){
                            alert('not check.');
                        }
                        else if($('input.chk').is(':checked')) {
                            var getid = $(this).parent().find(".chk").attr('checked', true).attr('id');

                            alert(getid);

                        }

                     });
```

My problem is that: I can get only the first id of radio button`chk1` when I check on other radio button.

Answer (score 1):

To get the id of the checked radio button

```
var getid = $('input.chk:checked').attr('id');
```

`$(this).parent().find(".chk").attr('checked', true).attr('id')` will return the id of the first element with class .chk inside the parent element which will always be the first radio element - not the checked one

If you want to be more specific in your search then use

```
var getid = $(this).parent().find(".chk:checked").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btnresult").click(function() {
    if(!$("input.chk:checked").length) alert("Not checked");
    else alert($("input.chk:checked").attr("id"));
});
```